# Undo the effect of method setText() of JEditorPane in one step not in three

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to undo the setText() method effect in a JEditorPane. Here is my code:

```
public final class UndoManagerTestForJEditorPane {

private final JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
private final UndoManager undoManager = new UndoManager();

public JComponent makeUI() {
    editor.setContentType("text/html");
    HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument) editor.getDocument();
    document.addUndoableEditListener(undoManager);
    editor.setText("Hello");

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("undo") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (undoManager.canUndo()) {
                undoManager.undo();
            }
        }
    }));
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("redo") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (undoManager.canRedo()) {
                undoManager.redo();
            }
        }
    }));
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("setText(new Date())") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String str = new Date().toString();
            editor.setText(str);
        }
    }));

    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    box.add(makePanel("Default", editor));

    JPanel pp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    pp.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pp.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return pp;
}

private static JPanel makePanel(String title, JComponent c) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
    p.add(c);
    return p;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new UndoManagerTestForJEditorPane().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The default behaviour is done with four steps:

1) Nothing is done, the cursor doesn't even move..

2) The cursor gets down with almost 10 lines under the inserted word..

3) The text get disappeared..

4) the old text appears finally..

So, instead of these steps, could we do it just only with one undo step like in this link for JTextField [JTextArea setText() & UndoManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433089/jtextarea-settext-undomanager), but with JEditorPane ?

The problem the replace method for JEditorPane does not get executed when setText() is called on JEditorPane...

Please any help ?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-undo-redo

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm already using this approach, the problem is exactly when using for example:

JEditorPane ed = new JEditorPane();
ed.setText("some text");

when I do undo, the behaviour is as described in the first post.

Any help please ?

Comment: Then you better provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I added the code as a demo, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a separate class (can be nested to directly access the necessary GUI elements, if you only have to do your edits with informations from one class) which extends `AbstractUndoableEdit`. You can save the exact old state that you want to load after one `undo` operation and the exact new state which you want to reload after a `redo` operation. You can then set the correct values in the `redo` and `undo` methods directly by overriding them in the `State` class. This could look like this:

```
public final class UndoManagerTestForJEditorPane {

private final JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
private final UndoManager undoManager = new UndoManager();

public JComponent makeUI() {
    editor.setContentType("text/html");
    HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument) editor.getDocument();
    //document.addUndoableEditListener(undoManager);  -> Not used anymore
    editor.setText("Hello");

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("undo") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (undoManager.canUndo()) {
                undoManager.undo();
            }
        }
    }));

    // New class to hold the state and load the correct string
    class State extends AbstractUndoableEdit
    {
        String oldText;
        String newText;

        State(String oldText, String newText)
        {
            this.oldText = oldText;
            this.newText = newText;
        }

        @Override
        public void undo() throws CannotUndoException {
            editor.setText(oldText);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canUndo() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void redo() throws CannotRedoException {
            editor.setText(newText);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canRedo() {
            return true;
        }


    }
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("redo") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (undoManager.canRedo()) {
                undoManager.redo();
            }
        }
    }));
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("setText(new Date())") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String str = new Date().toString();
            // Add a new edit by saving the old string (by calling getText) and the new string 'str'
            undoManager.addEdit(new State(editor.getText(), str));
            editor.setText(str);
        }
    }));



    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    box.add(makePanel("Default", editor));

    JPanel pp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    pp.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pp.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return pp;
}

private static JPanel makePanel(String title, JComponent c) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
    p.add(c);
    return p;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new UndoManagerTestForJEditorPane().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it works fine but it disabled the listener for the editions that I made before clicking setText. So how should I do to keep trace of the previous editions ? Thank you again

Comment: No problem, so it works now for you? I'm glad I could help you

Comment: Yes thank you so much, I have a new problem with JEditorPane, I posted here, thank you again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005483/jscrollpane-does-not-scroll-down-to-the-caret-position-because-of-image-in-jedit

Comment: Great, you're welcome. You should provide some code for your new problem. Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Hello, could you take a look on my new post ?
Thank you so much

Comment: Hello, sorry I was busy. It seems that your question was being closed in the meantime.

Comment: Well, this is the new post because I had problems with that post..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044987/jscrollpane-does-not-update-its-scroll-to-go-down-to-follow-the-caret-position-b

Comment: Hello, here is a new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180459/limit-characters-in-a-jformattedtextfield

Could you help me with that please ?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, I can try. Can you accept the answer from this question? Then people will see that this one is solved ;)

Comment: Done ;) it's not what I wanted but I resolved it in another way.. no problem

Comment: Could you take a look on the new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180459/limit-characters-in-a-jformattedtextfield ? Thank you